# I want to use a variable inside of the init function but I do not know how to access it

Tags: swift, uikit

Here is my code:

```
init(dataArray: DataArray) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.label.text = ""
        dataArray.data.forEach({ self.label.text?.append("\n\($0)")})
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

I have created a DataArray struct in another file and it is just an array of Strings. It is pulling the data from a getData function I have written in the backend. Currently this code works but I have created another function that allows me to setData. My problem is that I need to rerun the code to see the changes to the data that I am printing. I want to see the changes in real time so I need to call this line:

```
dataArray.data.forEach({ self.label.text?.append("\n\($0)")})
```

outside of the init function and I do not know how I can access the data array.

Comment: You cannot, from outside a function (like your `init`), access a variable that exists only within that function. You would need to set a _property_ of your object.

Comment: I think this might be a bit too open-ended to reasonably cover in a single Q&A style post like what StackOverflow offers, but to point you in the right direction I can give some suggestions: 1) Forget about files. _Values_ or don't live in one file or another. _Declarations_ can live in different files, or they can be in one file, it doesn't much matter; it's just mostly a convenience for organization. 2) Your init belongs on a class or a struct. Judging by the `call to super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`, it's probably a subclass of `UIView`. This initializer is well, initializing an ...

Comment: ...an _instance_ of your `UIView` subclass. If you want to access this init parameter somewhere else, you'll need to store it as a property of your object, and that pass a reference to your new object to the place where you want to access this data. They can then access that property and do whatever it is they need.